# Firestore - deep collection query in one loop

Tags: node.js, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions, firebase-admin

I have a firestore object like this :

```
{
  countries:[
    country1: {
      cities: [
        city1: {date_added: timestamp},
        ...
      ]
    }
    ...
  ]
}
```

So I would like **in one query** to get a list of cities. I know I could go like (I'm in firestore functions)

```
const cities = [];

admin.firestore().collection('countries/')
    .get()
    .then(countriesSnapshot => {
      countriesSnapshot .forEach( countryDoc => {
        admin.firestore().collection('countries/' + countryDoc.id + '/cities/')
          .get()
          .then(citySnapshot => {
            citySnapshot.forEach( cityDoc => {
              cities.push(cityDoc.id);
            });
          }).catch();
      });
    }).catch();
```

But this does a double foreach and I want to process only after everything has resolved. I could with `promise.all` but I wonder if there is a simpler way to go - something like

```
admin.firestore().collection('countries/{countryId}/cities').get().then(citySnapshot ...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, it looks like there is no possibility to make this happen in a specific subcollection = Frank's answer gave a solution that could work in some cases but won't in mine since my name isn't unique across my DB.

So my solution is to make it happen in two loops anyway but not one into the other - using Promises. Like so :

```
admin.firestore().collection('countries/')
  .get()
  .then(countriesSnapshot => {
    const citiesPromises = [];
    countriesSnapshot.forEach( countryDoc => {
      citiesPromises.push(admin.firestore().collection('countries/' + countryDoc.id + '/cities/').get());
    });
    Promise.all(citiesPromises).then(resources => {
      for (const resource of resources) {
        resource.forEach( doc => {
          // do stuff with doc.id or doc.data()
        });
      }
    }).catch();
  }).catch();
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to query across all `cities` collections, you can use a [collection group query](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/queries#collection-group-query):

```
let cities = db.collectionGroup('cities');
cities.get().then(function(querySnapshot) {
  querySnapshot.forEach(function(doc) {
    console.log(doc.id, ' => ', doc.data());
  });
});
```

This will return all cities across all countries.

Comment: Nice, but if I have another collection named city at a place I don't want to include, it would come as well. It would be great if it would be possible to `let cities = db.collectionGroup('cities', '/countries');` for example, so it would look for `cities` subcollections only.

Comment: Unfortunately collection group queries are currently globally based on name, and can't be based on path (believe me: I'd **really** like to see those too). So this approach requires that you have a unique name for the collection types, like `country_cities`. I also often find myself having to replicate data from the country into the city. As is usual with NoSQL databases: we have to modify our data model to fit the use-cases of our app.

Comment: Yeah, I had to denormalize, it's normal :) but here I'm working on a script for an app already in prod... Oh well I guess I will write a pre-script to copy the data I want somehow. Thanks